# Referencing XML columns in trigger bodies in DB2

Tags: sql, xml, triggers, db2

I need to create a trigger that inserts rows into a table (tableC) after inserting data into another table (tableA).

These are the tables:

```
tableA                tableB                  tableC
-----------------     --------------------    -----------------------------------
id    | xmlColumn     id    | referenceOnA    id   | extractedData | referenceOnB
(int) | (xml)         (int) | (int)           (int)| (varchar)     | (int)
-----------------     --------------------    -----------------------------------
42    | <xml>...      1     | 42              32   | 'string1'     | 2
28    | <xml>...      2     | 42              98   | 'string2'     | 3
...   | ...           ...   | ...             ...  | ...           | ...
```

This is the trigger statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger
AFTER INSERT ON schema.tableA
REFERENCING NEW AS n
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
    INSERT INTO schema.tableC (extractedData, referenceOnB)
        SELECT tmp.extractedData AS extractedData, b.id AS referenceOnB
        FROM schema.tableB b, XMLTABLE('...xQueryExpression' PASSING n.xmlColumn
            COLUMNS
                extractedData VARCHAR(100) PATH '.') AS tmp
        WHERE b.referenceOnA = n.id;
END
```

The insert statement in the trigger body should extract varchars from the `xmlColumn` in `tableA` and insert the the extracted data into `tableC`. I think the problem is that the `xmlColumn` is of type XML and referencing XML columns in trigger bodies is prohibited in DB2. According to [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.xml/src/tpc/db2z_triggerxml.htm) this restriction can be circumvented by using the `XMLTABLE` function (which I did)

But I'm getting the following error in DBEdit 2:

```
AN ERROR OCCURRED WHEN BINDING A TRIGGERED SQL STATEMENT.
INFORMATION RETURNED: 
SECTION NUMBER: 2
SQLCODE -270,
SQLSTATE 42997, 
AND MESSAGE TOKENS. SQLCODE=-20100, SQSTATE=56059, DRIVER=4.7.85
```

Any ideas?

---

Unrelated to the problem above:

When I execute the same statement in SQL Explorer I get this error:

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601,
SQLERRMC=<END-OF-STATEMENT>;(. 
AT MICROSECONDS MICROSECOND SECONDS MINU, DRIVER 3.65.77
```

After removing `BEGIN ATOMIC` and `END` I get an error message similar to the one thrown by DBEdit 2. How can it be that different database editors throw entirely different exceptions when executing the exact same statement?

I'm working on DB2 10 btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the manual page you are referring to, the restriction is on the use of XML data type in transition variables, which you are attempting: `PASSING n.xmlColumn`

The example there shows that your `INSERT` statement should look somewhat like this:

```
INSERT INTO schema.tableC (extractedData, referenceOnB)
    SELECT tmp.extractedData AS extractedData, b.id AS referenceOnB
    FROM schema.tableB b, schema.tableA a, 
         XMLTABLE('...xQueryExpression' PASSING a.xmlColumn
         COLUMNS
            extractedData VARCHAR(100) PATH '.') AS tmp
    WHERE b.referenceOnA = n.id and b.referenceOnA = a.id;
```